# Code changes to laravel blade views not updating cache

Tags: php, laravel, apache, view, laravel-blade

To start, I’m a noob with Laravel and I’m having an issue with my view cache.

Upon updating code within views, I am not seeing any of the corresponding changes on local host.

I’ve tried everything suggested within forums:

Clear cache on views, cache, and config.

Cleared Browser cache, Refreshed Browser.

Chmod to storage folder.

I’ve confirmed opcache settings within in php.ini are correct.

I’ve even switched code from windows platform to Ubuntu. And changes still haven’t updated.

I’ve even manually deleted the cache files with in the view folder, but upon refreshing browser, old code still populates in the view cache directory.

I’m running this with Apache,laravel 6, and php7.2. I’ve also served the application through artisan and I still receive same issue.

Please provide assistance whenever possible. Thank you.

Comment: never happened to me; i think youre missing some simple issue like looking at the wrong directory..

Comment: @Flame I was looking at the wrong directory. Thanks man